# ASP.NET Forms CustomCustomvalidator - always correct value

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I've created simple page in ASP.NET Forms and I need to use CustomValidator control. Here's the code:

`Page.aspx`

```
<asp:ListBox 
    ID="listControl" runat="server" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    onchange="toggleButton(this, document.getElementById('remove'))" />


<asp:CustomValidator 
    ID="fmValidator" 
    ControlToValidate="listControl"
    CssClass="IncorrectResult" 
    runat="server" 
    ValidateEmptyText="True" 
    ErrorMessage="..." 
    Text="..." 
    OnServerValidate="Validator_OnServerValidate" />
```

`Page.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Validator_OnServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs  args)
{
    if(isAdmin)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

The point is that I can catch an event in `Validator_OnServerValidate` with proper data but whatever I put in `args.IsValid` (I mean true or false) it always returns correct value - on the webpage everything is correct. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That was because page didn't reload on validating. All I had to do was enable client side validation.